# How to re-size .bmp file in C\C++?

Tags: c++, c, resize, bmp, cbir

I am doing a CBIR system as an assignment.There are 100 .bmp files,but they have different size,how to re-size them to a same size?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you use some library? If so there are a bunch of libraries for this...

Comment: Library is also ok.DO you know any good lib for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [CImg Library](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), it's quite easy to use. You can load your bitmap file then use one of the `resize` function.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a overkill, but you can take a look on ImageMagick.

Comment: To the contrary, I think this is a good answer. ImageMagick and a bash script and you'll be done in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at G'MIC, a command-line tool to batch image processing operations.
It is even more advanced than ImageMagick's convert tool.

Basically, you can call it like this :

```
gmic *.bmp -resize 128,128,1,3,3 -outputp resized_
```

to resize all your bmp images into 128x128 color images, and save them with filenames prefixed by 'resized_'.

G'MIC is available for Linux, Windows and Mac, at : http://gmic.sourceforge.net